# Alter RewriteRule to change parameter results

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my Apache 2 Directory configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/website/>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?operator=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?operator=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

If I enter

> example.com/website/a/b

then I see: `?operator=a&url=b`. This is fine and is what I expect.

If I enter

> example.com/website/a/

then I see: `?operator=a&url=`. This is also fine and expected.

---

My problem is the result of

> example.com/website/.

What I see is `?operator=index.php&url=`. I expected to see both parameters empty, but operator is populated with 'index.php'.

How can I alter my 'RewriteRule's so that the parameters are both empty when then there are no directories trailing after website as shown in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the rewritten URL to look like `/website/index.php?...`, I think this is what you want:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/website/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /website/index.php?operator=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/website/([^/]+)/?$ /website/index.php?operator=$1 [L,QSA]
```